# Induced emf in ring in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, induction

A metal ring is placed in a magnetic field. The ring has a gap in it though. As it falls through the magnetic field, is it true that it still experiences an induced emf and eddy currents but not a proper current?

Answer (score 1):

What's a "proper current"? A current going all the way around the ring? Clearly it cannot experience that if the ring has a gap in it. Like any metal object it will experience eddy currents when moving through a magnetic field.

Comment: Oh ok so it still experiences eddy currents but not like a full circuit? I just wasn't sure if it still had eddy currents. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Eddy currrents are small loops of current. They don't need geomerty of a ring or as such. They can form on discs, planes and pretty much in any conductor.

Assuming that you mean a net current around the ring as proper current, there won't such a current as the circuit is open (gap in the ring). However, there will be an EMF across the ends of the rings.